# Automatically updating package-lock.json

Tags: pnpm

I noticed a failing build on my CI, because I deleted the `package-lock.json`, because it seemed out of date anyway since I'm using `pnpm`. A proper `package-lock.json` does seem to be required though.

It's probably possible to run `npm install --package-lock-only` with a pre-push hook if the package.json was updated, but this takes a while and isn't very convenient.

Is there something I'm missing? I think this functionality should be built into `pnpm` to improve compatibility.

EDIT:
I don't think switching to `pnpm` on my CI is an option, since I'm writing a library that I want people to be able to install using `npm`.

Comment: if you use pnpm then just commit pnpm's lockfile and build with pnpm on the CI server (https://pnpm.js.org/docs/en/continuous-integration.html). There is a command (pnpm import) for converting package-lock.json to shrinkwrap.yaml but no vice versa.

Comment: @ZoltanKochan I don't really think this is an option and I'll update the question to explain why.

Comment: Currently, pnpm is more strict than npm, so if your package will work with pnpm, it will work with both npm and Yarn. https://medium.com/pnpm/pnpms-strictness-helps-to-avoid-silly-bugs-9a15fb306308

Comment: @ZoltanKochan If `npm` and `yarn` would be using the shrinkwrap.yaml, which they aren't. This is evident from having used `pnpm` while developing and the build failing in the CI using `npm`.

Comment: If you develop a library, not an app, then maybe just don't commit any lockfile. In that case, you're sure that you always get the very latest dependencies. This is how Sindre Sorhus maintains his libraries and he has thousands of libs on npm.

Comment: @ZoltanKochan I see he does indeed not have `package-lock.json`'s in his packages, but I still think it's important to have because the `npm` documentation says so and it's absence has clearly caused one failing build already.